# For loop inside for loop to sort items

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to use a for loop inside a for loop to sort items in an array, but instead some values gets duplicated, and I can't seem to spot what the problem is. My logic is not highly developed yet. I know that there are sort functions but this is part of a school assignment and we have to use the two for loops. I want the value of the "order" key to determine the array position of the object.

```
 var connection = await fetch('momondo.php')
  var jData = await connection.json()
  var aScheduleInOrder = jData
  for (var i = 0; i < jData.length; i++) {           

    for (var j = 0; j < jData[i].schedule.length; j++) {

      aScheduleInOrder[i].schedule[jData[i].schedule[j].order] = jData[i].schedule[j]
    }
  }
```

And here are the json objects inside the jData:

```
[  
  {     
  "currency":"DKK",
  "price":3000,
  "schedule":
  [    
    {"airlineIcon":"LH.png", "date":1581513600,"id":"SAS22","from":"C", "to":"D","waitingTime":120,"flightTime":240,"order":2},
    {"airlineIcon":"KL.png","date":1581510000, "id":"SAS33","from":"B", "to":"C","waitingTime":60,"flightTime":180,"order":1},
    {"airlineIcon":"DY.png","date":1581501600,"id":"SAS1","from":"A", "to":"B","waitingTime":0,"flightTime":80,"order":0}
  ]
},

{   
  "currency":"DKK",
  "price":5000,
  "schedule":
  [
    {"airlineIcon":"LX.png", "date":1581513600,"id":"SAS55","from":"B", "to":"C","waitingTime":120,"flightTime":240,"order":1},
    {"airlineIcon":"SK.png","date":1581501600,"id":"SAS44","from":"A", "to":"B","waitingTime":0,"flightTime":80,"order":0}

  ]
},

{     
  "currency":"DKK",
  "price":15000,
  "schedule":
  [
    {"airlineIcon":"AC.png","date":1581501600,"id":"SAS78","from":"A", "to":"B","waitingTime":0,"flightTime":80,"order":0}
  ]
}    
]
```

At position [1] in the array, inside the schedule array the first item, at position [0], has a key called "order" with a value of 1. This should according to my logic, with the two for loops, get moved to position [1] and the second item at position [1] should be moved to position [2] etc. This is what it should look like after:

```
[  
  {     
  "currency":"DKK",
  "price":3000,
  "schedule":
  [
    {"airlineIcon":"DY.png","date":1581501600,"id":"SAS1","from":"A", "to":"B","waitingTime":0,"flightTime":80,"order":0},
    {"airlineIcon":"KL.png","date":1581510000, "id":"SAS33","from":"B", "to":"C","waitingTime":60,"flightTime":180,"order":1},
    {"airlineIcon":"LH.png", "date":1581513600,"id":"SAS22","from":"C", "to":"D","waitingTime":120,"flightTime":240,"order":2}
  ]
},

{   
  "currency":"DKK",
  "price":5000,
  "schedule":
  [
    {"airlineIcon":"SK.png","date":1581501600,"id":"SAS44","from":"A", "to":"B","waitingTime":0,"flightTime":80,"order":0},
    {"airlineIcon":"LX.png", "date":1581513600,"id":"SAS55","from":"B", "to":"C","waitingTime":120,"flightTime":240,"order":1}
  ]
},

{     
  "currency":"DKK",
  "price":15000,
  "schedule":
  [
    {"airlineIcon":"AC.png","date":1581501600,"id":"SAS78","from":"A", "to":"B","waitingTime":0,"flightTime":80,"order":0}
  ]
}      
]
```

I hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, clear, you just want the order attribute sorted, not ordering the items inside the array? Then add the following in your second nested loop

```
aScheduleInOrder[i].schedule[j].order = j;
```

instead of

```
aScheduleInOrder[i].schedule[jData[i].schedule[j].order] = jData[i].schedule[j]
```

**EDIT:** After the original question was altered, hereby a new answer. Please try this code, it will create the new array from scratch looking up the correct scheduling order in the original array. Also quite readable from a teacher perspective:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jData.length; i++) {

    var currency = jData[i].currency;
    var price = jData[i].price;
    var schedule = [];

    var data = {
        "currency": currency,
        "price":    price,
        "schedule" : []
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < jData[i].schedule.length; j++) {
        data.schedule[j] = getScheduleByOrder(jData[i].schedule,j);
    }

    aScheduleInOrder.push(data);
}

function getScheduleByOrder(scheduleArray,order){

    for (var k = 0; k < scheduleArray.length; k++) {
        if (scheduleArray[k].order === order){
            return scheduleArray[k];            
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: No sorry, my bad, I just changed the "order" numbers quickly for illustration purposes. I've edited to post again. I want the "order" value of the object to determine the position of the object in the array. I apologize for the poor explanation. This is so complex to me :)

Comment: Ah ok, then the issue is that you are changing the order in the iteration. i.j = 0.0 becomes 0.1 and then you get in the next iteration of j to 0.1 which will stay as being 0.1 since it got changed in the previous iteration. Will get back with the answer shortly!  Just add a console.log like: console.log("changing order of " + aScheduleInOrder[i].schedule[j].airlineIcon + " from " + i + "." + j + " to " + i + "." + jData[i].schedule[j].order); and see what I am mentioning happening..

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `.sort()` Array method?
EDIT : Aaaah `this is part of a school assignment and we have to use the two for loops.` School assignments FTW

```js
let jData = [{
    "currency": "DKK",
    "price": 3000,
    "schedule": [{
        "airlineIcon": "SK.png",
        "date": 1581501600,
        "id": "SAS1",
        "from": "A",
        "to": "B",
        "waitingTime": 0,
        "flightTime": 80,
        "order": 0
      },
      {
        "airlineIcon": "KL.png",
        "date": 1581510000,
        "id": "SAS33",
        "from": "B",
        "to": "C",
        "waitingTime": 60,
        "flightTime": 180,
        "order": 1
      },
      {
        "airlineIcon": "LH.png",
        "date": 1581513600,
        "id": "SAS22",
        "from": "C",
        "to": "D",
        "waitingTime": 120,
        "flightTime": 240,
        "order": 2
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "currency": "DKK",
    "price": 5000,
    "schedule": [{
        "airlineIcon": "SK.png",
        "date": 1581501600,
        "id": "SAS1",
        "from": "A",
        "to": "B",
        "waitingTime": 0,
        "flightTime": 80,
        "order": 1
      },
      {
        "airlineIcon": "LH.png",
        "date": 1581513600,
        "id": "SAS22",
        "from": "B",
        "to": "C",
        "waitingTime": 120,
        "flightTime": 240,
        "order": 0
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "currency": "DKK",
    "price": 15000,
    "schedule": [{
      "airlineIcon": "SK.png",
      "date": 1581501600,
      "id": "SAS1",
      "from": "A",
      "to": "B",
      "waitingTime": 0,
      "flightTime": 80,
      "order": 0
    }]
  }
];

jData = jData.map( obj => {
    obj.schedule.sort( (a,b) => a.order > b.order ? 1 : -1); // sort by the "order" key ascending
    return obj;
})

console.log(jData)
```

Comment: Yes I wish I could use the sort function xD

Comment: Well, in real life, for a real job, we would use the `.sort()` function. `for` loops are not for sorting. Schools and their irrelevant assignments.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. But I also wish to understand why this does not work to develop my logic if that makes sense :)